# How can I use multiple templates in grafana?

Tags: go, grafana, graphite

One template measures time.
Another remaining template measures the Response Code.
We set "Define" in each message template and enter the define of each template in the conatct point.

But I can only receive one template message.
In this case, should I specify Alert Rule in "Message Template"?
What should I do if I need to specify?

I can only receive one template message. In this case, should I specify Alert Rule in "Message Template"? What should I do if I need to specify?